# Xcode continues to pull outdated PhoneGap

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

First, my issue.  I have built an iOS mobile app for a client in Xcode using PhoneGap.  On my machine, the app compiles just fine.  When I sent the app and all assets to my client for him to compile on his machine, it would throw an error and not load a PhoneGap header file.  We dug around and it turned out that the header file (PGPlugin.h) was literally not in his installation of PhoneGap.  So I zipped up my PhoneGapLib directory and he replaced his PhoneGapLib files with mine.

Yet, when he tried to run, it did not discover the header file.  As part of the debugging process (I'm a rookie on Macs and Xcode, so this is probably very basic), I would rename my PhoneGapLib directory to something like PhoneGapLibOLD just to ensure that when I did that, Xcode would not find anything it needed, verifying that it was indeed pulling from the source files each time it compiled.  But that is not the case!  Even when I rename the PhoneGapLib directory, it compiles as if nothing has changed.

Cleaning the project, cleaning the build folder, and clearing simulator data do not change things.

How can I get Xcode to essentially refresh PhoneGap so that it can properly discover the files I sent to my client?  Or to ask the question differently, why is it that when I rename my PhoneGapLib directory, Xcode compiles just fine as if nothing has changed?

Answer (score 0):

Does he have PhoneGap or Cordova? It's been renamed to since moving over to Apache.

There is a plugin migration guide in the Cordova DMG, e.g. replacing references to PGPlugin.h with CDVPlugin.h amongst other things.

Comment: It's PhoneGap.  Thanks for the response, I wasn't aware of Cordova.